# Trouble setting up Flask in a virtualenv in an Aptana project on Mac

Tags: python, macos, bash, flask, virtualenv

I'm new to virtualenv and Flask, and I'm trying to set up both in a project directory in my Aptana workspace. I used the terminal to `cd` into my project directory (`Noodling`) and there I created a new virtualenv (`venv`) according to the directions on http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/. I then activated the space using `. venv/bin/activate`, which appears to work because `(venv)` appears before the terminal command line. However, when I run `pip install Flask` the terminal replies `-bash: pip: command not found`.

I've been googling around trying to answer a few questions to get to bottom of this problem, and better understand the process itself, and eventually decided to post here:

1) Why is the pip command not working?

2) Was I supposed to put the Flask files I downloaded somewhere first before trying to install them?

3) Should I have performed the `virtualenv` command on my project directory `Noodling` instead of in it?

4) When I work in this project in Aptana, should I turn on the `venv` in the commandline before I begin?

Feel free to answer bits and pieces of my questions; I'm pretty new to this mix of tools. Thanks for your time helping me better understand how to use them! Cheers!!

Comment: for pip / venv , you should have a look at [the guide dedicated to the OSX installation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/)

Comment: @FoxMaSk Hmmm. I appear to be up a creek without a paddle on this one. All the recommended downloads on the OSX installation page are for Lion and I have Snowleopard. After much googling, it appears many more can't get Xcode an the commandline tools either. But why did `pip` work on `virtualenv` and not on `Flask`?

Comment: I think I may have made things worse now. My system's to old to get a version of Xcode (OSX 10.6.8), so I downloaded and installed GCC, and installed Homebrew, but after running `brew doctor` I received a warning that because I have the Enthought Distribution of python installed, it will/may(?) clash with Homebrew. Going to keep trying to trouble shoot this one. Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @FoxMaSk in the comments above, I finally tracked down the hangup.

Here are responses to each of my own questions:

1) The pip command was not working because it was not installed (comes with Homebrew, which I didn't have). This was confusing because I had successfully installed `virtualenv` using `easy_install` which also typically comes with Homebrew. It turns out I'd gotten `easy_install` with the [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/) but Enthought does not come with `pip`. At that point I installed Hombrew, only to discover that it clashes with Enthought (will issue a warning when you run `brew doctor` as recommended. Ugh.

Eventually I uninstalled Enthought, and installed [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) in its place, because it does not clash with Homebrew. As a bonus, Flask (the goal at the end of this rabbit trail, ) comes prepackaged with Anaconda. Whew. I now also have the `pip` command.

2) Moot, as I now have Flask installed via Anaconda

3), 4) I realized these two questions are beyond the original scope of my question about problems installing Flask, and are probably best asked in their own thread if necessary. For now, I plan to do a bit more research on my own.

Cheers!